# Navigate from Detail view controller out of UISplitViewController to a normal full-sized UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I want to navigate to a `UIViewController` out of a `UISplitViewController`, when somebody will click on a table cell in the detail View controller.

Setting a segue to an `UIViewController` didn't work properly.

How can I exit the `UISplitViewController` and show a full-sized `UIViewController` and navigate back to the `UISplitViewController`?
I want to display some details on the `UIViewController`.

Comment: which is the error that you get when you create a segue?, showing a new view controller modally works to me

Comment: At the moment it is not segueing, though i set the segue and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the UIViewController on the UISplitViewController by using method.

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added:
    AppDetailsView *appDetailsView = [[AppDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppDetailsView" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:appDetailsView animated:YES];

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

I finally get the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/d056894/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/A4DED6AF-CBFF-490D-B46E-FE53BFFA9599/appname> (loaded)' with name 'AppDetailsView''

Comment: @Niklas this code works for. I am not sure why it is giving you this error. Can you make sure you have the AppDetailsView.xib file in the project?

Comment: Hmm I'm only having a storyboard and not a xib in the project.

Comment: Initialize the viewController as follows:     

    AppDetailsView *appDetailsView = (AppDetailsView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AppDetailsView"];

instead of initWithNibName:

Comment: Nice this is working for me, but i need to set the Storyboard ID in the Identity tab in the interface builder to AppDetailsView.

Comment: do you know how to navigate back to the UISplitViewController?

Comment: Use a delegate to dismiss the viewController like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649834/dismissviewcontroller-not-working)